# Searching nearby lat_lng in Google places api (python)

Tags: python, google-maps, google-api, google-places-api

I am trying to find all places nearby a certain location in lat_lng. However I get an error when searching for a lat_lng instead of a location (location='location'). I've got a key for the Google places API Web Service and Google Maps Geocoding API. Accoring to https://github.com/slimkrazy/python-google-places this should be enough.

This is my code and my error message:

```
YOUR_API_KEY = 'API_KEY'
google_places = GooglePlaces(YOUR_API_KEY)

query_result = google_places.nearby_search(
        lat_lng='52.0737017, 5.0944107999999915', 
        radius=100,
        types=[types.TYPE_RESTAURANT] or [types.TYPE_CAFE])

for place in query_result.places:
     place.get_details()
     print '%s %s %s' % (place.name, place.geo_location, place.types)
```

**Error message:**

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\googleplaces\__init__.py", line 281, in nearby_search
    lat_lng_str = self._generate_lat_lng_string(lat_lng, location)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\googleplaces\__init__.py", line 590, in _generate_lat_lng_string
    else geocode_location(location=location, api_key=self.api_key))
TypeError: format requires a mapping
```

Anyone who knows how to fix this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69744146/16447945 could you guys help me out with this please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [github](https://github.com/slimkrazy/python-google-places) you provided, the reference section states the lat_lng parameter is of type *dict*:

> lat_lng  -- A dict containing the following keys: lat, lng (default None)

Do the following instead:

```
query_result = google_places.nearby_search(
        lat_lng={'lat': 52.0737017, 'lng': 5.0944107999999915}, 
        radius=100,
        types=[types.TYPE_RESTAURANT] or [types.TYPE_CAFE])
```

To see the query_result, simply do:

```
query_result.raw_response
```