# Python, Google Places API - FIND Places nearby given a set of lat/lon

Tags: python, pandas, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a data frame that consist of Store ID and its lat/lon.
I want to iterate through that dataframe and for each store ID find key places nearby using the google api.

for example input:

```
Store-ID  LAT       LON
     1     1.222      2.222
     2     2.334      4.555
     3     5.433      7.2343
```

Output should be (in a new dataframe):

```
Store-ID   Places found     ......
    1          school
    1          cafe
    1          cinema
    1          bookstore
    .
    .
    .
    2          toy store
    2          KFC
```

and so on ..........

so far I have tried the following but fail to create a new data frame that would match the output format I mentioned above

```
map_client = googlemaps.Client(API_KEY)
theta = 0
search_string =['school','store','bank','restaurant','clothing_store','health','mosque','hospital','car_dealer','finance','electronics_store','university','home_goods_store']
distance = km_to_meters(0.1)


sc = []
business_list = []
import time
import math
for i, row in POI_copy.iterrows():
 print(i, row[0], row[1], row[2])
 for string in search_string:

    coordinates = (row[1], row[2])
    response = map_client.places_nearby(
    location = coordinates,
    keyword = string,
    radius = distance
        )
    business_list.extend(response.get('results'))
    print(f'we have found a place and we are appending for store code{row[0]}')
    sc.append(str(row[0]))
    next_page_token = response.get('next_page_token')

    while next_page_token:
        time.sleep(2)
        response = map_client.places_nearby(
        location= coordinates,
        keyword=string,
        radius=distance,
        page_token=next_page_token)
        business_list.extend(response.get('results'))
        next_page_token = response.get('next_page_token')
        print(f'we have found a place and we are appending for store code{row[0]}')
        sc.append(str(row[0]))
```

I also want to know if we could extract more info for each place like rating, timings, busiest hour of the day, busiest day of the week and append to the dataframe